# max-height Transition keep child element always on bottom of parent

Tags: css

I'm fighting with quite easy problem.
Sections change their max-height on hover.
the small span article `article__tag` should always position at the bottom of its parent (the green line) no matter how much the row will grow and share its easing animation and delay.

This is what I have:

```css
section{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgreen;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


section:hover {
  max-height: 400px;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

article {
  flex:1;
  height: 200px
}

.article__tag {
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  top: 120px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

section:hover .article__tag {
  bottom: 0;
  top: inherit;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>A</article>
  <article><span class="article__tag">tag</span></article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>B</article>
  <article><span class="article__tag">tag</span></article>
</section>
```

https://codepen.io/t-book/pen/LYpjVPz

My problem is, on mouse leave the white label jumps up quickly. Further, I've defined it's top with `165px` a value which I cannot foresee as the rows have different content.

How can I position the label always on current max-height bottom?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep article_tag at bottom always:

```css
section{
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  max-height: 150px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgreen;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}


section:hover {
  max-height: 400px;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}

article {
  flex:1;
  height: 200px
}

.article__tag {
  background: white;
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 0px;
  transition: all .5s ease-in-out;
  transition-delay: .3s;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <article>A</article>
  <article><span class="article__tag">tag</span></article>
</section>
<section>
  <article>B</article>
  <article><span class="article__tag">tag</span></article>
</section>
```

Comment: shame on me didn't see the forest because of trees! thanks!